# How to make apache show other message, not " 403 forbidden "when a user try to access a website?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2

i find someway like change httpd.conf , but i can't find it with ubuntu server

and redirect  , but I don't know how to solve this problem?

thank all.

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.webreference.com/programming/apache_errors/) explains how to set custom error pages.

Answer (score 1):

[`ErrorDocument`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument)